# Mysql 8.0 syntax error check manual for proper syntax

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x

what's wrong with this line of code?
whenever I run it it shows syntax error 'mysql' check the corresponding server version.

```
import mysql.connector
import builtins
import importlib.util
import os

v=os.getcwd()
loc=""

for i in v:
    if i == "\\":
        loc += "/"
    else:
        loc += i


print(loc)

def crt():
    m=mysql.connector.connect(host="localhost",user="root",passwd="****")
    mc=m.cursor()
    mc.execute("create database if not exists mydb")
crt()

m=mysql.connector.connect(host="localhost",user="root",passwd="****",database="mydb")
mc=m.cursor()

mc.execute("source "+loc+"/mydb.sql;")
```

normally for mysql when I apply the following code it works.

```
use mydb;
source C:\Users\15fri\OneDrive\Desktop\s3ts\mydb.sql
```

as for the for loop section in the previous code I converted the backslashes to forward slashes since some time the location in the code even works with forward slashes..

Comment: Pretty sure that error is some where in the `mydb.sql` file..

Comment: 'Check manual for proper syntax'. What happened when you did that?

Comment: i cant find no solution for my problem in the manual

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is probably that `source` is not an SQL command and that it's only available from within the mySQL CLI.

Try reading the script file and passing its contents as a string to `mc.execute()`

In response to your comment CrazY JoN, I'm no Python programmer but I was thinking of something like this:

```
sql_script_file = open("source "+loc+"/mydb.sql;",'r')
sql_script = sql_script_file.read()
sql_commands = sql_script.split(";")    # assuming the commands in the script have to be executed one at a time
for cmd in sql_commands:
    mc.execute(cmd)
```

Comment: can u plz give me an example... thanks for the answer though

Comment: i found another way too but concept remained the same as u said it to be